# How to resolve 'Variable not in scope' error when running ghci?

Tags: ghci

After installing ghci stack, when I run just ghci (version 9.2.7) in terminal and enter some expression such as 1+1 I get the following error:

:1:2: error:
Variable not in scope: (+) :: t0 -> t1 -> t

I have been unable to parse what the error message is suggesting or where to look for the issue. Thank you very much for your consideration.

Comment: How did you start `ghci`, without implicit prelude?

Comment: I've been starting ghci by entering "ghci" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You likely started `ghci` with `-XNoImplicitPrelude`, in that case it does not import the prelude.

You can import the prelude to load the basic functions:

```
ghci> import Prelude
ghci> 1+1
2
```

You should inspect the `.cabal` or `.stack` file of your project if it contains a directive to disable loading the `Prelude` implicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. when I typed "import Prelude" into the prompt I got "<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘Prelude’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘base-4.16.4.0’.
    You can run ‘:set -package base’ to expose it.   Then entering ":set -package base" made it work. I'm not sure why it was hidden though.

Comment: @CCB: likely in the `*.cabal` file you did not write `base` in the `build-depends` section.